# How to combine two differently multi-indexed pandas dataframes by multiplying column by column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I'm trying to combine. They each have a multi-index, but those indices have no overlapping levels. The dfs are each the same width.

df1

```
               v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
location year
       A 1990   1  3  2  1  4
         2000   2  5  0  3  1
       B 1990   6  2  1  2  1
         2000   3  4  5  0  0
```

df2

```
         v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
age sex
  5   M   0  0  1  0  1
      F   1  0  1  1  1
 10   M   1  0  0  0  0
      F   0  1  1  0  0
```

I want to make a new dataframe that has entries for every combination of the two indices, with values equal to the product of the values in corresponding columns:

result

```
                       v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
location year age sex
       A 1990   5   M   0  0  2  0  4
                    F   1  0  2  1  4
               10   M   1  0  0  0  0
                    F   0  3  2  0  0
         2000   5   M   0  0  0  0  1
                    F   2  0  0  3  1
               10   M   2  0  0  0  0
                    F   0  5  0  0  0
       B 1990   5   M   0  0  1  0  1
                .            .
                .            .
                etc
```

I think I could join the dfs and then multiply column by column, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it more automatically, since pandas built in multiplication is so much faster.

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer help, You can accept it or upvote it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `numpy` +`pandas`

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame(data=np.concatenate(df1.values[:,None]*df2.values),
           columns=df1.columns,
             index=np.concatenate(df1.index.values[:,None]+df2.index.values))
df_new.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_new.index)
df_new
Out[162]: 
             v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
A 1990 5  M   0   0   2   0   4
          F   1   0   2   1   4
       10 M   1   0   0   0   0
          F   0   3   2   0   0
  2000 5  M   0   0   0   0   1
          F   2   0   0   3   1
       10 M   2   0   0   0   0
          F   0   5   0   0   0
B 1990 5  M   0   0   1   0   1
          F   6   0   1   2   1
       10 M   6   0   0   0   0
          F   0   2   1   0   0
  2000 5  M   0   0   5   0   0
          F   3   0   5   0   0
       10 M   3   0   0   0   0
          F   0   4   5   0   0
```

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! Do you have an explanation of what that's doing?

Comment: @Cliff df1.values[:,None]*df2.values, this is to build the matrix , using every single value from df1 add the whole df2